# How many Distinct triangle can be made from stick of length N?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

You are given a stick of length N. You want to break it in three pieces such that it can form a triangle. How many distinct triangles can you make? Two triangles are equal if all the side lengths are same when sorted in ascending order of length. So (1, 3, 2) is same to (3, 1, 2) because their side lengths are same if we sort them, which is (1, 2, 3). But (1, 3, 4) is not same with (1, 2, 3). Suppose the lengths of three pieces are X, Y, Z (X ≤ Y ≤ Z) respectively. Following constraints should be maintained:

```
X, Y, Z > 0.
X, Y, Z is an integer.
X + Y >= Z
X + Y + Z = N
```

For example if N = 14, then there are 7 triangles: (1, 6, 7), (2, 5, 7), (2, 6, 6), (3, 4, 7), (3, 5, 6), (4, 4, 6), (4, 5, 5).

Comment: It might help to know that the triangle inequality test can be simplified here to check the sum of two smaller parts exceeds the larger part.

Comment: Hint: The longest side cannot be bigger than $N/2$, and cannot be smaller than $N/3$.

Comment: (1,6,7),(2,5,7), and (3,4,7) will not make  triangles.The sum of any two sides must be strictly greater than the third side.

Comment: @user254665 , look at the constrains , X + Y >= Z , where on earth you found strictly greater ?

Comment: @BarryCipra, The OP's constraints are X,Y,Z >0, which rules out (0,7,7).  Additionally, the (rather odd variation of the) triangle inequality given is $X+Y\ge Z$.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A005044 gives the sequence for the number of *non-degenerate* triangles (i.e., not counting those with $X+Y=Z$).

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Barry Cipra, the number of nondegenerate triangles is given in [OEIS A005044](http://oeis.org/A005044).  Allowing degenerate ones (due to the restriction $X+Y \ge Z$ permitting equality) adds $\lfloor \frac n4 \rfloor$ when $n$ is even and makes no change when $n$ is odd.  This is because to have $X+Y=Z$ with $X \le Y \le Z$ we must have $Z$ even, then we count the values for $X$ as from $1$ to $\lfloor \frac Z2 \rfloor$  I didn't find the resulting sequence in OEIS.

Comment: $3 + 4 = 7.$ Did I miss a constraint?

Comment: @DavidK:  I don't understand what the question is referring to.  What is it about?

Comment: Z is odd in the first comment.

Comment: I think you meant "to have $X+Y=Z$ ... we must have $n$ even". Sorry for the obscure comment before, I just now figured it out.